# Get r_liteprofile and r_emailaddress - api.linkedin.com/v2

Tags: oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

How to get email address and lite profile from linkedIn api v2 (api.linkedin.com/v2)

Can not get email from https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?oauth2_access_token=xxxx

Requested &scope=r_emailaddress%20r_liteprofile

Answer (score 21):

you need to make a separate call

GET `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/emailAddress?q=members&projection=(elements*(handle~))`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/sign-in-with-linkedin?context=linkedin/consumer/context#retrieving-member-email-address

Comment: Such an obfuscated request/response for a very common use case, not to mention all the existing integrations breaking. Great way to support the developer community. Developers, developers, developers, right? /s

Comment: Does anyone have a snippet to see how to integrate these different API calls for email and liteprofile? I still can't get my head around this issue after having read their docs for the past few days.

Comment: @rags2riches What do you mean "integrate"? You have to make one call to `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me` endpoint for the basic profile and another call to the `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/emailAddress?q=members&projection=(elements*(handle~))` endpoint to get the email in their ridiculous handle format.